# Help me to understand this prove about derivatives and limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

i need help with this theorem. I see the prove but i dont understand the end of the proof:

Theorem: Let $f:\;(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose $c\in(a,b)$ is such that f is differentiable in $(a,c)$ and in $(c,b)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f'(x)=L$. Prove $f$ is differentiable in $c$ and $f′(c)=L$

The proof:

Be $ϵ>0$. Now, consider $δ>0$ such that $x−c<δ⟹|f′(x)−L|<ϵ$.
Now, if $x−c<δ$, we have that $|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-L|=|f'(\xi)-L|<\epsilon$, where the equality is given for some $ξ$ between $c$ and $x$ by the mean value theorem, and the inequality by the way we defined $δ$. It follows that $\lim\limits_{t \to c^+} \frac{f(t)-f(c)}{t-c}=L$.

Ok, this is only a part of the proof, because the other part is very similar. I dont understand this part: "by the mean value theorem, and the inequality by the way we defined $δ$. It follows that $\lim\limits_{t \to c^+} \frac{f(t)-f(c)}{t-c}=L$." I dont see the implication, please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand that the mean value theorem tells you that
$$
\frac{f(x)−f(c)}{x−c}=f′(ξ)
$$
for some $ξ$ strictly between $c$ and $x$, so that when $0<|x-c|<δ$ also $0<|ξ-c|<δ$ holds?